# Grails: how to use createLink in a Filter?

Tags: grails, filter

Short question:

How can I use [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html#createLink) in a Filter?

I'm getting error:

> No signature of method:
>   MyFilters.createLink() is applicable
>   for argument types...

My code is

```
createLink(controller:'home')
```

This code works inside a Controller, but not in a Filter.

Comment: is that a typo on your createLink example?  I don't think a space is legal in the name of the controller (since it will try to add Controller after the name when searching).

Comment: ok, I'll fix. There is no space

Comment: Have you tried `g.createLink(controller:'home')`

Comment: Yes...I got "No such property: g for class: MyFilters"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib
...
new ApplicationTagLib().createLink([controller: 'home'])
```

Answer (score 5):

In Grails 2.* you can inject the `grailsLinkGenerator`, could be a bit cleaner:

```
def grailsLinkGenerator
...
grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller: 'home')
```