# use createLink in BootStrap

Tags: grails, groovy

really simple what I want to do:

I want to use the method 'createLink' in the BootStrap class! how can I do it?! some suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the answer from [Grails: how to use createLink in a Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153164/grails-how-to-use-createlink-in-a-filter) :

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib
...
new ApplicationTagLib().createLink([controller: 'home'])
```